# Why isn't JavaScript Every method working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I cannot figure out why the array method 'every' isn't working here.
(working on roguelike dungeon crawler game.)

I have an array of objects like this:

```
   { 
    x: newrm.x,
    y: newrm.y + 10,
    w: newrm.w,
    h: newrm.h,
    centerx: newrm.centerx, 
    centery: newrm.centery + 10
   }
```

All I'm trying to do is test whether every element in this new array passes a following test (this is preventing collision of player with walls) via the Every method:

```
if (newdraw.every(isWithin)) {
    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    this.setState({ dungeon: newdraw });
}
function isWithin(obj) {
  console.log('this is the obj and this is the player', obj, player);
  return obj.x < player.x + player.w && obj.x + obj.w > player.x && obj.y < player.y + player.h && obj.h + obj.y > player.y;
}
```

Seems not every element is being checked, as only a total of two objects are being logged to the console.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The `.every()` method will stop iterating as soon as it finds an element that doesn't meet the condition.

Comment: in other words, if ANY `newdraw` results in false, the code inside the if block wont run

Comment: I suspected it was something simple like that I failed to grasp about Every.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for a better method?

Comment: "Better" needs some criteria for evaluation. From "*test whether every element in this new array passes a following test*", `every` is doing exactly what it should. If you want either the non-compliant or compliant elements in a new array, use [*filter*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.filter).

Comment: You could probably swap it for ... `.forEach()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 2):

That is how every works. It stops when it finds a falsy value. See MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

> The every method executes the provided callback function once for each
>   element  present in the array until it finds one where callback
>   returns a falsy value. If such an element is found, the every method
>   immediately returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for every()

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "Look",
    "lastName": "Alike",
    "email": "lookalike@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Matt",
    "lastName": "Kaddy",
    "email": "mkad@gmail.com"
  }
]

var newData = {
  "name": "Different",
  "lastName": "Person",
  "email": "lookalike@gmail.com"
}


data.every((x) => {
  if ( ( x.email.toLowerCase()) === ( newData.email.toLowerCase()) ) {
    console.log("Stops here because it returns false")
    return false;
  }
  //If its return true it will below run the below log.
  console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For first you need to understand how the condition are heard for every method for example

```
const arr = [9, 5, 2, 6, -23, 6, 8, 1, 9, 2, 0].every((el) => {
  return el > 0;
});
console.log(arr);
```

we say to Array.every method check is every element more then 0 ? when cycle appear to index 4: -23 he break the cycle and return false value